# Rows disappear when removing duplicates libreoffice

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, duplicate

I pasted a lot of data in Column A.

Then I removed duplicates:

`Data > Filter > Standard Filter > More Options > No Duplication`

Now I'm stuck in row 2632, i.e. I can´t scroll up to rows above 2632.

What's my issue?

LibreOffice 3.6.

Comment: I don't understand, how are you "stuck"? perhaps a screenshot? What version are you running?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you accidentally hide your cells. If you select all the cells by clicking in the little blank area in the top left, (or press Ctrl-A) then right click on a number and click **Show** your data should re-appear.

[image]

Comment: Could be, document long gone and forgotten. Maybe this will help someone. I didn't know of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Also when you select the 'no Duplication' option the filter will have some text(normally the first row content), clear it before you hit okay. This should resolve the rows disappearing problem.